# GROUP BY returns wrong count in SnowFlake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below is a row from a SnowFlake query. This is the only row in the result with this information (i.e., this row is unique).

```
ID   ACCOUNT_NUMBER  DATE_1       DATE_2
123  347             2017-10-19   2017-10-29
```

I ran a GROUP BY like below to count the number of rows in each group. I got 3 for the above row. Shouldn't I get 1?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DATE_1, DATE_2, COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

```
ID   ACCOUNT_NUMBER  DATE_1       DATE_2       COUNT
123  347             2017-10-19   2017-10-29   3
```

I expected to see count of 1 for this row, but I got 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is correct. The `DISTINCT` is applied after the grouping and has not effect in provided query.

> [Docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html)
> Typically, a SELECT statement’s clauses are evaluated in the order shown below:
>
> 1. From
> 2. Where
> 3. **Group by**
> 4. Having
> 5. Window
> 6. QUALIFY
> 7. **Distinct**
> 8. Order by
> 9. Limit

Both below queries produces the same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DATE_1, DATE_2, COUNT(*) 
FROM TAB
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;

SELECT ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DATE_1, DATE_2, COUNT(*) 
FROM TAB
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

[image]

To apply DISTINCT it should be provided before grouping(subquery)

```
SELECT ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DATE_1, DATE_2, COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DATE_1, DATE_2 FROM TAB)
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

or as a part of aggregate function:

```
SELECT ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DATE_1, DATE_2, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DATE_1, DATE_2) 
FROM TAB
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

[image]

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TAB(ID INT,
                           ACCOUNT_NUMBER INT,
                           DATE_1 TEXT,
                           DATE_2 TEXT)
AS
SELECT 123,  347, '2017-10-19', '2017-10-29' UNION ALL 
SELECT 123,  347, '2017-10-19', '2017-10-29' UNION ALL 
SELECT 123,  347, '2017-10-19', '2017-10-29';
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer and editing my question.